# Center div on html line

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with html. I am trying to set a html line and on that line I have to set a div with text. Here is the example, but it is a photo. I would like to get this in html.

[image: Photo]

I hope someone can help me.

Edit:

I know how to get a line in html and I know how to get this yellow div with the text. The problem is. How do I get the yellow div on the line. This is my current result.[image: Current situation]

Comment: I would recommend the answer of Ahmed Salama as Flex is not compatible in all browsers yet.

Comment: @MuhammadOmarElShourbagy Can you tell me which browsers are compatible with Flex, because it is a mobile application. I tried it on Chrome an on Safari and both browsers are compatible.

Comment: @D.Bronder, Please find the compatibility list here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` and **pseudo-elements**. Here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/824/)

```css
.element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.price {
  background: #FEC538;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.element:before,
.element:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 5;
  height: 3px;
  background: #C3C3C3;
}
.element:after {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="price">Save 35%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain what the :before and :after does?

Comment: Those are pseudo-elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before, in this case i used them to create lines.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
<div class='c1'>
  <span>save 35%</span>
</div>

.c1{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.c1:before{
  content:'';
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  background:#CDCCCD;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  margin:-1px 0 0;
}
.c1 span{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 15px;
  background:#FEC538;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
}
```

see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/6tonuvg6/

Answer (score 0):

That will do..
**Html**

```
<div class="center-div"></div>

**Css**
body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.center-div
{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `width`, and set `margin:auto;`.

[image: Imgur]

```css
div.c2 {
  margin:auto;
  width:80px;
  text-align:center;
  
  /*color*/
  background-color: #FEC538;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=c2>Save 35%</div>
<div>
```